# How to write Couchbase N1QL query in spring data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I want to write a query to find a list of strings which contains sub-strings,
e.g

```
 "xyz-1",
 "xyz-2",
 "xyz-3",
 "xyz-4".....
```

Above is list of Strings i need to find but i have input as xyz only and not the fullname xyz-1.

In couchbase server i have implemented the query as below,

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE ANY v IN namelist SATISFIES v LIKE '%xyz%' END;
```

which will give me all the list name containing xyz.
But implementing in Spring boot application its not working.

Below is my spring boot @query menthod

```
@Query("Select * from `test` where #{#n1ql.filter} And ANY v In namelist SATISFIES v Like '%$1'% END within #{#n1ql.bucket}")
List<String> findBynameList(String name);
```

and below is my pojo class ,

```
    @Id
    private String car_id;
    @Field
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @Field
    private List<String> namelist;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right side of the LIKE must be string or query named/positional parameters of string.

If query named/positional parameters inside the string will not be replaced. You have '%$1'% , it will look for $1 not value.

If you want look for value write like this

```
v LIKE $1    ===> supply $1 as "%actualvalue%"
v LIKE "%" || $1 || "%"
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for me by adding '%' || $1 || '%'